# UI Only Updates As Intended When Editing Through Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to make a single column width cascading menu. I have main categories with subcategories. The subcategories contain unknown amount of items which are displayed in two columns as boxes. Otherwise everything is in a single column.

Hierarchy looks like this:

```
 MainCategory 1 | Vertical Layout Group 
      Text (category title)
      Subcategory | Vertical Layout Group | Content Size Fitter
          Text (subcategory title)
          ItemContainer |Grid Layout Group |Content Size Fitter
              item1
              item2
              item3
              item4
      Subcategory | Vertical Layout Group | Content Size Fitter
          Text (subcategory title)
          ItemContainer |Grid Layout Group | Content Size Fitter
              item1
              item2
 MainCategory 2 | Vertical Layout Group
```

I've made a script that only leaves the clicked subcategory active and disables every other Subcategory GameObject.

When I go to play mode and start clicking on things the positioning of the UI elements goes wrong. Mainly some items appear to be positioned poorly.

However when the game is still running and in Scene view I manually try to move a locked UI element, everything all of a sudden falls into place. I would guess this is because some of the UI element event functions aren't being fired at appropriate times.

How should I organize my UI for it to be displayed correctly? What excatly is triggered when I try to move the UI elements in scene view? Can I trigger that from code?

Comment: Is there a question in here? Do you have some code to share?

Comment: It seems that the nested content size fitters are breaking it. When an itemContainers content size fitter updates the parents content size fitter doesn't. Turning the parents content size fitter on and off after each update fixes it >_>